# The bias of $\hat \sigma^2$ for the population variance $\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics

It is given that the bias of an estimator of $\hat \theta$ for parameter $\theta$ is defined as $\Bbb E(\hat \theta) -\theta$. How to find the bias of $(\hat \sigma)^2$? Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: The hard part is finding $\mathbb{E}\left[\widehat{\sigma}^2\right]$. Search for something like "expected value of sample variance" on this site or elsewhere.

Comment: Proofs that the sample variance is unbiased may be found at this page (see the "Proof of correctness" sections): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n$ be iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Consider the quantity 
$$Q=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2$$
where $\bar x$ is the sample mean. Using the so-called "shortcut formula", we get
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - n\bar x^2$$
We can find the expected value of $Q$ as follows.
\begin{align*}
E(Q) &= E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right) - nE(\bar x^2) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nE(x_i^2) - nE(\bar x^2) && \text{linearity of expectation} \\
&= n[E(x_i)^2 + Var(x_i)] - n\left[E(\bar x)^2 + Var(\bar x)\right] && \text{decomposition of variance} \\[1.2ex]
&= n(\mu^2 + \sigma^2) - n(\mu^2 + \sigma^2/n) \\[1.2ex]
&= (n-1)\sigma^2
\end{align*}

From here, you can consider estimators of the form $\hat\sigma_c^2 = cQ$. Which value of $c$ corresponds to the estimator you are interested in? Sometimes people take $c=\frac{1}{n}$ which will lead to a biased estimate (the "method of moments" estimator). Sometimes $c=\frac{1}{n-1}$ which corresponds the unbiased sample variance (also the MLE). If you are interested in minimizing MSE of the estimator, you would take $c=\frac{1}{n-2}$.